# Decrease clang parse/reparse time with chained precompiled headers?

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, pch, pth

I'm working on text editor (almost IDE) and i'm using llvm/clang behind the scenes (tokenizing, diagnostics). Almost every file that is edited includes main header file which includes some headers too which include some other headers (tree of included files):

```
UserFile.h
L----MainHeader.h
     L----string.h
     L----device.h
     |    L----(in some conditions)---concreteDevice.h
     L----math.h
     |
     ...
```

The main idea is skip reparsing headers that remain the same during editing 'UserFile.cpp' in `clang_parseTranslationUnit` and `clang_reparseTranslationUnit` invocations.

I've read about Clang's [chained precompiled headers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/PCHInternals.html#id13) or even [modules](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/PCHInternals.html#id14) which seems to be what i need.

I've generated PCH for `MainHeader.h` like `clang++ -x c++-header MainHeader.h -emit-pch -o MainHeader.h.pch` and used it like `clang++ -include-pch MainHeader.h.pch ...`. I'm not sure if it's PCH for the whole headers tree (chained) or for that file only (most likely).

**Do i need chained precompiled headers since there is `CXTranslationUnit_PrecompiledPreamble` clang option?**

**How can i generate chained precompiled headers?**

Headers tree is pretty complicated because of multiple `#ifdef SOME_CONDITION .. #include <SomeHeader.h> #endif` and it's pretty difficult to understand the whole tree  and precompile `PCH` for each header file manually (but i do know arguments `-DSOME_CONDITION` to pass which affect inclusions tree).